# What is the difference between SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, SENSOR_DELAY_UI and SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST in Android

Tags: android, android-sensors

Can anybody tell me what is the difference between `SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL`, `SENSOR_DELAY_GAME`, `SENSOR_DELAY_UI` and `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` in Android sensors.

Where should a developer use all these things? What will user feel by using all these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

int SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST    get sensor data as fast as possible
int SENSOR_DELAY_GAME   rate suitable for games
int SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL rate (default) suitable for screen orientation changes
int SENSOR_DELAY_UI rate suitable for the user interface

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one application reading sensor values with all the above options. There is no difference values between SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST and SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL.

Comment: yes @Barak is right. the difference is in time. How often the sensors are polled for values.

Answer (score 35):

Here are some approximations based on tested results:

> ```
> Accelerometer, SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST: 18-20 ms
> Accelerometer, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME: 37-39 ms
> Accelerometer, SENSOR_DELAY_UI: 85-87 ms
> Accelerometer, SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL: 215-230 ms
> Orientation Sensor, SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST: 16-17 ms
> Orientation Sensor, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME: 37-39 ms
> Orientation Sensor, SENSOR_DELAY_UI: 77 ms
> Orientation Sensor, SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL: 224-225 ms
> ```

You can also define your own rate, for example 100ms.

```java
int READINGRATE = 100000; // time in us
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mLinearAccelerometer, READINGRATE);
```

However the rate is just an approximation, if you need an accurate rate it is better to use a timer.

Answer (score 7):

read this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST 0 microsecond
SENSOR_DELAY_GAME 20,000 microsecond
SENSOR_DELAY_UI 60,000 microsecond
SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL 200,000 microseconds(200 milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

My results with devices:
Honor 4C Android 5.1.1
Xperia Z3 Android 6.0.1
for `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`

```
Approximate values:

For samplingPeriodUs: 0ms:
Honor: 4-12ms, long time(1min) 10ms
Xperia: 1-5ms, long time(1min) 3ms

For samplingPeriodUs: 30ms:
Honor: 4-12ms, long time(1min) 7ms
Xperia: 7-21ms, long time(1min) 20ms

For samplingPeriodUs: SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL:
Many tests from internet: Accelerometer, SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL: 215-230 ms
Honor: 4-11ms, long time(1min) 10ms
Xperia: 6-114ms, long time(1min) 14ms

Omitted:SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, SENSOR_DELAY_UI

For samplingPeriodUs: SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST:
Many tests from internet: Accelerometer, SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST: 18-20 ms
Honor: 3-12ms, long time(1min) 8ms
Xperia: 1-5ms, long time(1min) 5ms
```