# How to read only once from Android build in Accelerometer per second?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, android-sensors, sensormanager

With help of sensorManager I am reading accelerometer reading. Currently slowest setting ie SENSOR_DELEY_NORMAL ,accelerometer  reads around 10 times every second. Is there any way by which it can reduce sending reading , may be once every second.

```
 @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

        if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            y = sensorEvent.values[1];
            z = sensorEvent.values[2];
            rootSquare = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2));
            
            //it reads every second 10 times ie 200 millisecon
}


 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelorometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044158/what-is-the-difference-between-sensor-delay-normal-sensor-delay-game-sensor-de), you could also define your own rate, for example 1000 ms = 1s:

```java
 @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

        if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            y = sensorEvent.values[1];
            z = sensorEvent.values[2];
            rootSquare = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2));
            
            //it reads every second 10 times ie 200 millisecon
}


 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    int READINGRATE_ONE_SEC = 1000000;
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelorometer, READINGRATE_ONE_SEC);

    }
```